# Adding data ordering by date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to add values separately  by date in order. Suppose there're several values with same date with a particular field. I wamt to sum up those data and want to have a particular row with one date. oredered by date.

Comment: Can you post the code you've already tried? that would make it easier to help

Comment: sound like you want a group by date? whats your code/results

Comment: You will need to GROUP BY that date column and aggregate the other columns. We're all unsure what you're asking about exactly, providing a sample data and what you want to achieve will help us help you.

Comment: It's done. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

So let's say you have some data like this:

```
DATE              VALUE
------------------------------
2017-01-01        100
2017-02-01        50
2017-01-01        75
2017-02-01        25
```

What it sounds like you want to do is take those 4 rows and combine them down to 2, one for 2017-01-01 and one for 2017-02-01, is that correct?

If so, you just need to do an INSERT with a SELECT and GROUP BY on the origin data.

So if I am trying to INSERT to Test_Table_One and my data was in Origin_Table_One, I would do:

```
INSERT INTO Test_Table_One
SELECT DATE, SUM(VALUE)
FROM Origin_Table_One
GROUP BY DATE
```

Does tht make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   create table #temp
(
    Date date,
    Sum bigint
)


create table #tempVarious
( 
    Date date,
    value bigint
)

insert into #tempVarious
values
    (cast(getdate() as date), 1),
    (cast(getdate() as date), 1),
    (cast(getdate() as date), 3),
    (cast(getdate() as date), 5),
    (cast(getdate() as date), 6),
    (cast(getdate() as date), 8),
    (cast(getdate() as date), 3),
    (cast(dateadd(day,-1,getdate()) as date), 1),
    (cast(dateadd(day,-1,getdate()) as date), 3),
    (cast(dateadd(day,-1,getdate()) as date), 6),
    (cast(dateadd(day,-1,getdate()) as date), 2),
    (cast(dateadd(day,-1,getdate()) as date), 1)

insert 
into #temp
select date
    , sum(value)
from #tempVarious
group by date

select * 
from #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are very new in SQL, please read these two tutorials about **GROUP BY** https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp and **ORDER BY** https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

```
SELECT DATE_COLUMN, SUM(VALUE_COLUM)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY DATE_COLUMN
ORDER BY DATE_COLUMN
```

A variant in case you want to order by descending

```
ORDER BY DATE_COLUMN DESC
```

In case your column is of type **DateTime** and you have different times in a single date

```
SELECT CAST(DATE_COLUMN AS DATE) AS DC, SUM(VALUE_COLUM)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY CAST(DATE_COLUMN AS DATE)
ORDER BY DC
```